# How do I connect guest Kali VM to internet through NAT (network works, internet doesn't)?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, internet, proxy

Alright, I'm having some really weird problems with my VM, and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I got it set up to where I can ping my host machine, I can even ping other hosts on the network. I can also ping google.com but for some reason it's unusually slow. We do use a proxy, and I have oracle virtualbox set to use that proxy. I've tried various configurations of using the proxy or not on the guest kali VM, all to no avail. Pinging google.com gives me.

```
PING google.com (173.194.46.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord08s13-in-f14.1e100.net (173.194.46.110): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=39.5 ms
```

So it's slow as dirt for reasons unknown to me, and if I try to browse there in iceweasel I get nothing ever. It just spins for all eternity. And again, I've tried no proxy, and I've tried the same proxy settings Virtualbox is using. I've tried setting the http_proxy environment variable in bash, and that didn't change anything either.

Anyone have any idea what's going on or where I can go for my next troubleshooting step? I'm relatively sure it shouldn't be getting blocked by the firewall, but not 100% sure. I don't know what VM traffic coming over a NAT connection would look like to the firewall, or even what port(s) it would use.

Comment: What is "slow as dirt"? Just web browsing?  Your ping response time (`39.5ms`) is reasonable, do you get that consistently?  Have you tried accessing webpages using something like `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: It slows down the entire command line, not just the ms response time. It takes 5-6 seconds for it to show the "PING google.com" message, then another 5-6 before it gets the reply. Ctrl+C Also takes an unusual amount of time to respond in this case, whereas any pings to the network behave normally.

If I do wget google.com I see `--2014-12-18 11:52:57-- http://google.com/ \n Resolving google.com (google.com)... IPs \n Connecting to google.com (google.com) | 173.194.46.98|:80... failed: Connection timed out.` After looking at some logs, I think it IS the firewall aferall, which is odd...